# Can we send value of input text field from one function to another using button action in apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

my one function is

```
function createFormSection(section, inputNames, opt_prefills) {
       var widget = CardService.newTextInput()
      .setFieldName(Txt_home)
      .setTitle(home);
       section.addWidget(widget);
      var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('sendemail');
      var textButton = CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText("Forward")
      .setOnClickAction(action);
      section.addWidget(textButton);
  }
```

second one is

```
function sendemail(event) {

}
```

Can i get value of text field(Txt_home) in second function in apps script?

Answer (score 0):

I done it, it's to much easy actually.
Using one line in second function.

```
var txt_input = event.formInput.txt_home;
```